# IsFile, IsDirectory Test Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, freebasic

I'm trying to convert a program from Linux to use on Windows, and it calls `test -f`, or `test -d` on Linux. I need it to do the same thing on Windows. Is there a built-in command, or another program I can use to do the same thing?

I'm programming using FreeBASIC (horrible, but it's what I got).

EDIT: An external program is the best option here. I've looked at the API, and it's not good.

Comment: Why is this tagged `batch`? Do you want a batch file solution or a FreeBASIC one?

Comment: Yeah, batch, like `test -f` on linux. Just edited it to reflect that.

Comment: add some quick info to my answer about how you might be able to sort out your own tool (even if you don't know C++ you might be able to cut out the crust from that sample and then ask other questions here to fix any remaining problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of FreeBasic before but looking at the help there's a `DIR` command that supports using `fbDirectory` as one of the attribute patterns to filter for.
And looking slightly further down on that page I just saw that they have a sample for checking if the objects found are files or directories. Just look [here](http://www.freebasic.net/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=KeyPgDir), look at the second example on that page.

Not sure what exactly those test commands do, but if you want to test if a specific object is a directory you should be able to call `Dir("exactname", fbDirectory, something)` I'd thought. And then you could test for a file by putting a Not in somewhere (assuming that FreeBasic supports that).

Edit: To make your own tool, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365522%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)'s a sample that shows a tiny C++ app that could easily be changed to look for directories or not. Look for the `FindFirstFile` in the sample and shortly after that it checks if it's readonly, which could be changed for FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY.

Comment: Yeah, that would be good if it worked 100%. I read somewhere that Dir() is buggy, which is not documented. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @bradlis7: If the language features are buggy, you might be better of following Ed's suggestion :). However, if you can execute external executables and get a return value it would be easy to write a tiny exe in C++ or something to look for this (you could probably find some sample code for this easily) and thne just create the tool yourself with some free C++ compiler.

Comment: Well, I ended up using Dir() and fbDirectory. It seems to work. I'm stuck with freebasic, unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

you can use test.exe just like under linux

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about FreeBASIC, have you looked into vbscript? You could use the FileSystemObject

```
Dim fso, msg
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FolderExists(fldr)) Then
   'Do Something here
Else
   'Do Something
End If
If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
   'Do Something here
Else
   'Do Something
End If
```

Comment: If I had not created 2,000 lines of code for Linux, I would be ok with doing it. An external program would work: `exec("isfile filename")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Kiwi for FreeBasic in order to check if a path leads to a file or directory. You can find Kiwi on Github (https://github.com/nsiatras/kiwi)

```
#include once "kiwi\kiwi.bi"
#include once "kiwi\io.bi"

' Declare a new file
Dim myFile as File = File("C:\Users\nsiat\Desktop\Test.txt")

' Check if file exists, is a File or is a Directory
print "File exists: " & myFile.exists()
print "Is file: " & myFile.isFile()
print "Is Directory: " & myFile.isDirectory()
```